# What do you call those little explosions you see in barbecues and bonfires?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm not talking about the one caused by grease, but the one that occurs spontaneously. A little *puff* that sends thousands of sparks around.

Comment: This is a constructive subjective question. I hope answers use [SE's hints](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), and provide reasonably long, not short, answers that explain “why” and “how” in a constructive, fair, and impartial tone, sharing experiences over opinions
and backing up any opinion with facts and references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it "crackling"...

Comment: I thought *crackling* was the sound a fire makes.

Answer (score 1):

Wow... No two dictionaries have the same definitions for this, but you could use *flare*, or *flare-up* or "sudden flare". (Or, "little explosion")

Answer (score 1):

There is quite a bit of scope here for using onomatopoeic words like *snap, bang, pop, crack* and the like, particularly if you double up the descriptive verbs to make the intended meaning clear:

> *The bonfire sparked and popped, and the damp logs that lay uppermost began to steam.*